# HTML5 - Create dynamically an image from a local path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to create an HTML image, if I have only a path to a local file? I tried to use a filereader, but the mere path does not work. how can I solve the issue?

JS

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = {
     $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
   reader.readAsDataURL("file:///C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.jpg  ");
```

Comment: You can't read files from a `file://` protocol for security reasons. You can turn off the security in chrome at least in the browser options if this is for some internal testing etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple tool I have made for reading files in JavaScript:

## Fiddle

The JavaScript code is:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onerror = function(ev) {
    $('#output').html('=== Error reading file ===');
}
reader.onload = function(ev) {
    $('#output').html(ev.target.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

When you select an image file it will present you with a base64 dataURI of the image.

I recommend not trying to select a file that's not an image, I don't know what'll happen.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
var x=document.createElement("img");
x.src="C:\data\images\test.jpg";
x.style.height="50px";
document.getElementById('whereimgoing').appendChild(x);
```

Also I should add that if this is on a website then it will depend highly on browser security

Answer (score -1):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
 $('#myImg').attr('src', reader.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL("file:///C:/Your/path/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.jpg");
```

Should be fine, if access to local files is granted (check your browser settings or try if it works when deployed on a server (either localhost or www.yourserver.com).. Local files can always cause some troubles as browser behave differently. Also try to not use the temp folder.